# Ubuntu 13.04 Install says there is "Not Enough Space"

Tags: installation, 13.04, disk-usage

"Not Enough Space"? I have plenty of space! What space is it talking about? How can I fix it?

Not too much additional info to give:

For starters, my `/boot` area is 243 Mib according to GParted.

1. I clicked the Upgrade button on the Update window
2. It proceeded to download some workfiles
3. It started the Upgrade process
4. Showed a dialog with a list of things it was going to do
       (Upgrading Ubuntu to version 13.04)
5. Step 1 was finished OK (Preparing to upgrade)
6. Step 2 almost finished (Setting new software channels)
7. Then it crashed at sub-step "Calculating the changes"

Error text:

**Not enough free disk space**

> The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 26.0 M free
>   space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 5,029 k of
>   disk space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages
>   of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.

Comment: This is a very vague answer, with little to no information to answer upon. Please elaborate more.

Comment: By the way, I already tried the "sudo apt-get clean" with no change in the result.

Comment: The error says "not enough **free** space", and not "not enough space". Your /boot might have 243 MB of size, but I guess only 20.9 MB is free out of those 243, and hence the installer complains. Can you verify this fact?

Answer (score 1):

Install ubuntu-tweak-tool in your current system. Open janitor, Check all options in system. It will remove old kernels from your `/boot` and lot's of space will be available after cleaning. You will able to upgrade system.

Answer (score -1):

`/boot` is the partition which has the bootloader, kernels and all other important stuff. Perhaps you had installed updates so many times in the past and whenever the kernels are updated they dont delete the older versions. They leave them in `/boot` itself. Please delete older files from `/boot`. Your problem should be resolved.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178944 Dec  5 21:02 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   176764 Dec  5 21:02 memtest86+.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  5127408 Mar 26 01:50 vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5355920 Apr 18 00:12 vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  2900893 Mar 26 01:50 System.map-3.5.0-27-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3059890 Apr 18 00:12 System.map-3.8.0-19-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   148096 Mar 26 01:50 config-3.5.0-27-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   154942 Apr 18 00:12 config-3.8.0-19-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   852365 Mar 26 01:50 abi-3.5.0-27-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   918868 Apr 18 00:12 abi-3.8.0-19-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15456711 Apr 30 06:21 initrd.img-3.5.0-27-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16158431 Apr 30 06:26 initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Apr 30 06:30 grub
```

This is how my `/boot` directory looks like. If I were to clean up, I would delete **all** the files which have `3.5.0.27` in their names. Because, `3.5.0.27` is, most likely, older than `3.8.0.19`

Comment: Uninstall the kernels through the package manager. Don't just delete the files.